# Multiple values in XML parser orchesta/parser with Laravel

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I am having issues getting multiple values from an XML document with the same name. I am using Orchesta/Parser with Laravel.

The XML is built up like this:

1 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 2 1

```
    'images' => ['uses' => '1.2.3.4'],
```

This way I am only getting the first result of 4, but there are like 10 4's.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a package I created. It will work perfectly with Laravel and even has a global Laravel helper `xml_to_array()`.

https://github.com/mtownsend5512/xml-to-array